# Kotlin DSL with optional fields

Tags: kotlin, dsl, kotlin-dsl

I'm currently in the process of learning about Kotlin DSLs.

I've been playing around with it for a while now but I'm unable to solve my use case. I have a simple DSL, and I don't care too much of the types it has as long as I can achieve a syntax like this:

```
    private fun getObj(): SET {
        return SET {
            ITEM {
                A = null
                B = "Hello world"
                C
                // D - exists in DSL but omitted here
            }
        }
    }
```

In the background, I now want to distinguish between certain values set in the `ITEM` block. `B` is easy, it is simply the value, but it becomes hard for `A` and `C`. Somehow I'm not able to differentiate between `null` and `no value` set. Currently my builder looks like this, but I'm open to changing it to achieve the syntax above:

```
class ITEMBuilder {
    var A: String? = null
    var B: String? = null
    var C: String? = null
    var D: String? = null

    fun build() = ITEM(
        ItemValue(A),
        ItemValue(B),
        ItemValue(C),
        ItemValue(D)
    )
}

class ItemValue(val include: Boolean? = false, val value: String? = null) {
    constructor(value: String? = null): this(null != value, value)
}
```

When I have my final object, I want to be able to tell 4 different stages for each field under ITEM:

- value set
- null set
- no value set
- field omitted

I tried different types, but had no luck since most things impact the syntax. I also tried to change the getter/setters in the builder, to maybe catch the update there and have an additional internal property that gets updated - but neither `get` or `set` are called for null/no value. Also tried to change the fields to functions but then I have ugly parenthesis `()` in the DSL syntax.

Would be great if somebody could help me figure this out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use receivers to achieve that. Here's an example with a single parameter (field in this case)

```kotlin
//Use like this
val item = ITEM {
        A = "Yay"
        B //Not omitted, but also not set
        //C can be omitted
        D = null
    }
```

This is equivalent to

```
Item(//Included and set to "Yay"
     a=ItemValue(include=true, hasBeenSet=true, value="Yay"), 
     //Included, but not yet set
     b=ItemValue(include=true, hasBeenSet=false, value=null), 
     //Not included, and so not yet set
     c=ItemValue(include=false, hasBeenSet=false, value=null), 
     //Included, and set to null (Same as A)
     d=ItemValue(include=true, hasBeenSet=true, value=null))
```

You can do this with the help of extra fields of type `String?` and override their setters to modify the actual fields of type `ItemValue`. I included a `hasBeenSet` property in `ItemValue` to show whether or not it has been set.

To mark properties as included without setting them, you can override the getters so they modify the actual fields to make them `ItemValue(true, false)`, which means they're included but not set.

```
class Builder {
    var A: String? = null
        set(value) {
            a = ItemValue(true, true, value)
        }
        get() {
            a = ItemValue(true, false)
            return field
        }
    var B: String? = null
        set(value) {
            b = ItemValue(true, true, value)
        }
        get() {
            b = ItemValue(true, false)
            return field
        }
    var C: String? = null
        set(value) {
            c = ItemValue(true, true, value)
        }
        get() {
            c = ItemValue(true, false)
            return field
        }
    var D: String? = null
        set(value) {
            d = ItemValue(true, true, value)
        }
        get() {
            d = ItemValue(true, false)
            return field
        }

    var a: ItemValue = ItemValue(false, false)
    var b: ItemValue = ItemValue(false, false)
    var c: ItemValue = ItemValue(false, false)
    var d: ItemValue = ItemValue(false, false)

    fun build(): Item {
        return Item(a, b, c, d)
    }
}

fun ITEM(setters: Builder.() -> Unit): Item {
    val builder = Builder()
    builder.setters()
    return builder.build()
}

data class Item(val a: ItemValue, val b: ItemValue, val c: ItemValue, val d: ItemValue)
data class ItemValue(val include: Boolean, val hasBeenSet: Boolean, val value: String? = null)
```

[Here's the link to the Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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). You can run it and see the output for yourself.

Comment: This looks good and is solving for the omitted case. However it is not solving for `B` and `C`, a null value and no value. The desired outcome would be that the ItemValue class shows `include=true` for all but the omitted case.

Thinking more about it, I would most definitely have to expand the `ItemValue` class, the desired object outcome would look something like this:
`-> isIncludes, Value, isEmpty` and then the use cases would look like:

`A: ItemValue == (true, A, false)`
`B: ItemValue == (true, B, false)`
`C: ItemValue == (true, C, true)`
`D: ItemValue == (false, D, true)`

Comment: Your updated code covers the case for null values, however it is not able to distinguish between omitted values and values that are not set, ```A = null // works```, ```B = "Hello world" // works```, ```C // doesnt work```, ```// D - exists in DSL but omitted here // works```

Comment: Yep, that solved it. Thanks for all the help. Let me read through the code, to understand how this works.